# MS Access Split DB - Front end creating backups

Tags: ms-access

We are using an Access front-end pointing to a SQL database for the back end. Users have copies of the front-end on their desktops that are periodically creating backups as a recovery function.

I've inherited this application and am not intimately familiar with Access. The SQL DB is functioning fine.

Currently, we're just deleting the backups and staff are able to complete their data entry.

I'm hoping someone might have some insight on what might be causing this and give some troubleshooting suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, that's not normal behaviour, but someone might have programmed it to do so. It sounds like someone might design a database to create a backup periodically to prevent loss of forms and queries.

Comment: Backup of data should not be a user task, and backup of the frontend should not be needed. Instead, launch a fresh copy for each user: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

Comment: Occasionally frontend will backup itself if it encountered some kind of error during runtime that could cause corruption. I just delete them whenever I see them and just to be safe replace the user's working copy. I think this is an issue with accdb not accde.